# Why is 4.real invalid syntax?

Tags: python

`dir(4)` shows `real` as one of its attributes, and if I access it through an index first like `[4][0].real` or `int(4).real`, then it's working (displays `4`)

So why is `4.real` invalid syntax?

Comment: 4 is a primitive type and those do not have any class members/functions

Comment: @Smac89 - That is true for C/C++, but this is Python.  `4` is an integer object in Python and it has many members, including `.real`.  The OP's problem is that the parser thinks `4.real` is a float because of the `4.`.  He needs to use parenthesis `(4).real` or a space `4 .real`.

Comment: exactly. it's parsed as [FLOATCONST][IDENTIFIER], which makes no sense and *is* a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @iCodez Why not post this as an answer? (oh just noticed it was marked as duplicate)